# Android: Hidden buttonbar like in Hotmail app

Tags: android, show-hide, buttonbar

Consider the Hotmail app for Android. When you check an e-mail item, three buttons appear at the bottom: [Mark Read] [Mark Unread] [Delete]
When you uncheck it, the buttons go away again.

What's the layout for this? I've tried this, but it yields scrolling problems at the bottom (can't see last item):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/mark_read" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I also need to show/hide this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the visibility of bottom linearlayout will show/hide it. You'll need to give it an id and then

```
LinearLayout bottomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someId);
bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)// or View.VISIBLE
```

As for the scrolling problem, that occurs because the RelativeLayout overlays view components, so you can either show/hide the button overlaying the bottom of the ListView or change the Relativelayout to a LinearLayout so that the ListView ends before the button and change the visibility.

Though I'm not sure this will look very good when you suddenly show the button and the ListView has to resize itself.

Note on visibility

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

will remove the view from the layout and other component may resize due to this. However using

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

keeps the space the view took up in the layout and simply makes the view invisible and no resizing will occur.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I use a `LinearLayout` I can't put the buttonbar at the bottom as in my sample code. Or can I? The Hotmail app solves this elegantly (the buttonbar shows a shadow too). Not sure what the best approach is... will try your hide/show code to begin with.

Comment: This solves my other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393385/android-scrollview-in-relativelayout-with-buttonbar

Comment: You can with a linear layout you just need to wrap your layout in another linearlayout and set the orientation to vertical, also I've edited my answer with a note about visibility