# Where to put ScrollView in this Android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have ImageViews and TextViews in my layout (activity is inside a Tab), and a button at the bottom. I want the whole layout to be scrollable, but not the button at the bottom. Now where to put the `<ScrollView ...>` and `</ScrollView>` (keeping in mind that only one child is allowed inside ScrollView)?
It seems like wherever I put these, it doesn't scroll. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <TextView ... />

</LinearLayout>

<Button />  //This button should be fixed at the bottom right corner, and should NOT be scrolled

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the complete code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Taurus" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Leo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Scorpio" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s11" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Aquarius" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Aries" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancer" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Libra" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Capricorn" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Gemini" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Virgo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Sagittarius" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/s12" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Pisces" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Exit" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set wrap_content for the layout_height of the scrollview. On the other hand I also set the android:layout_above property of the scrollview. I tried an example with other pictures, please see the code below. I tried it and it works.

> ```
> <ScrollView
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/scrollview"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/button1" >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Taurus" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView5"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView5"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Leo" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView8"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView8"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Scorpio" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView11"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView11"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Aquarius" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Aries" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView4"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView4"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Cancer" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView7"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView7"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Libra" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView10"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView10"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Capricorn" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView3"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Gemini" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView6"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView6"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Virgo" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView9"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView9"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Sagittarius" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView12"
>                 android:layout_width="75dp"
>                 android:layout_height="75dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView12"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Pisces" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:text="Exit" />
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I wish you the same! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to put a ScrollView inside the RelativeLayout. This ScrollView should have a single linearlayout child. So the final sketch of your layout file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
//here come your 3 LinearLayouts
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Be sure that the ScrollView is not behind the button. Somebody already had a similar problem. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393385/android-scrollview-in-relativelayout-with-buttonbar

Comment: I added the complete code in the edit. Please check it. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I created a separated post with the solution. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

do this way:

```
<ScrollView ...>
<RelativeLayout>
//all your other tags
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When using `<ScrollView ... >`, keep in mind that `ScrollView` hosts only one direct child at a time. That means their should be single Child Layout (i.e `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout` etc) so in this case you will host your current `RelativeLayout` (which is holding other `LinearLayouts`) as a child.

and one more thing, take schemas line to the `ScrollView` tag.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>
```

---

**Edit:** do a slight change, put

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
```

inside `ScrollView` tag.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried! But it is still not scrolling. Has it anything to do with the TabHost I am using?

Comment: change your `RelativeLayout`'s height to `wrap_content`. otherwise upload any screenshot, describing exact what do you want.

Comment: I added the complete code in the edit. Please check it. Any idea why is it not scrolling? Thanks for the replies.